# Pass html element value to laravel Blade IF

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

i need help how to pass **&{currentQuestion.id_soal}** to laravel if, example:

```
@if($s->id == &{currentQuestion.id_soal} )
```

this is the script:

```
 output.push(
        `<div class="slide">
            @foreach ($soal as $key => $s) 
            @php
              $ids = ${currentQuestion.id_soal}
              @if($s->id ==  $ids  )
                <p>{!!$s->soal!!}</p>
              @endif
            @endphp
            @endforeach

           <img src="{{ asset('/soal_gambar${currentQuestion.gambar}')}}" style="max-width: 100%;" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
           <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
         </div>`
      );
```

Comment: Hi there, can you post your code inside the question instead of as a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for updating your post. Your question is unclear and I don't understand what you are trying to do, could you clarify?

Comment: the main question is "how to put html element value as laravel blade if parameters?"

Comment: i found laravel blade directive, ill try it

Answer (score 1):

Use this `{!! $data !!}`, it displays content without escaping HTML special characters.

Source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data